# How to display data on button clicked on next page in Angular TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display right data from the image I linked at the bottom, on another page depending on what id it has and which button is clicked.

Do I have to generate for instance a checkout component that the data from skie.component.html is displayed after button is clicked?

What will I need to do in skie.component.ts? redirect to another page using routing

Anyway, hope you understand my problem and sorry if there is not enough info, I appreciate all the help I can get

skie.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Skie } from '../../entities/skie';
import { skiEquipmentsData } from '../../ski-equipments';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-skies',
  templateUrl: './skies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./skies.component.scss']
})
export class SkiesComponent implements OnInit {

  skies: Array<Skie> = new Array<Skie>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.skies = skiEquipmentsData;
  }

}
```

skie.component.html

```
<div class="card-deck" *ngIf="skie">
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img-top" [src]="skie.imageUrl">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 class="card-title">{{skie.header}}</h2>
    <p class="card-text">{{skie.description}}</p>
    <div [ngClass]="{'limitTextHeight': isReadMore}">
    <p class="card-text" [innerHTML]="skie.extendedDescription"></p>
  </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" (click)="showText()">
      {{ isReadMore ? 'Read More': 'Read Less' }}
    </button>
    <div class="buttonRight">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Välj Paket</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the list with info/data with id
ski-equipments.ts

```
    export const skiEquipmentsData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      header: "Nybörjarpaketet",
      description: "Detta är ett perfekt paket för dig som inte är så van vid att åka, men ändå vill få ut det mesta möjliga av din tid i backen",
      extendedDescription: "Paket består av:<p><ul><li>Skida: Atomic Performer FB</li><li>Bindning: M10 GripWalk</li><li>Pjäxa: Nordica Trend LX 20/21</li></p>",
      imageUrl: "/assets/images/beginner.png"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        header: "Medelpaketet",
        description: "Om du har åkt en del och vill ha en lite mer avancerad utrustning ska du välja detta paket. Här får du den bästa kompromissen mellan lättåkta skidor och bra prestanda.",
        extendedDescription: "Paket består av:<p><ul><li>Skida: Atomic Redster WT</li><li>Bindning: M10 GripWalk</li><li>Pjäxa: Atomic Hawx Magna 100 21/22</li></p>",
        imageUrl: "/assets/images/medium.png"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        header: "Expertpaketet",
        description: "När du vill ha det bästa som går att få för att känna att din skidåkning kan nå nya höjder är detta paketet för dig. Med denna topputrustning garanterar vi att du kommer att få en riktigt minnesvärd tid i backarna.",
        extendedDescription: "Paket består av:<p><ul><li>Skida: Rossignol BlackOps Stargazer (Open) 21/22</li><li>Bindning: Touring Bindings Marker Alpinist 10 21/22</li><li>Pjäxa: Rossignol Alltrack Elite 90 GW (98 mm) 21/22</li></p>",
        imageUrl: "/assets/images/expert.png"
    }
  ];
```

See image to understand what I want to be displayed
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUNRj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a details template page the same for every product you can go like this:

In app-routing.module.ts add your new details component with id param:

```
  {
    path: 'skie/:id',
    component: SkieDetailsComponent
  }, // ...
```

Then in SkieDetailsComponent use ActivatedRoute to catch the param

```
skie: any;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.skie = skiEquipmentsData.find(s => s.id === id);
}
```

now you can display and use data on details page like {{ skie.description }} etc.

Last thing will be to add routerLink to your SkiesComponent:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/skie', skie.id]">Välj Paket</button>
```